# Reverse engineering a .Net web app. Errors after deploying

Tags: asp.net, reverse-engineering

I'm attempting to do an update to something that I have no code for. I have pulled the source using Reflector, created a new project and can build it successfully after my changes. I can run a local copy pointed at the proper database with no issues.

However, when I deploy to the site I keep receiving the error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

I don't see anything in the web.config that would make me think it's looking for a specific version, and I saw nothing in the GAC.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Was the original assembly signed with a strong name key?

Comment: I looked at it in Reflector and it was null.

Comment: Does the Windows file version (e.g. 1.2.0.0) of the DLL that you're reverse engineering match the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion attributes in your new project?

Comment: Yes, I made sure the versions matched what I saw in Reflector. 1.0.0.0